# Named Tuple workaroung for change Value in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples, namedtuple, setattribute

in my project i need change namedTuple variable's value, but it's impossible because is a "Tuple" and they are immutable.
But i want overwrite **setAttr** function for use _replace function of namedTuple.

```
from collections import namedtuple

flag=False
if flag:
    class Log:
    x=1
    y=2
else:
    LogNT = namedtuple("Log", "x, y", defaults=[1, 1])

class Log(LogNT):
    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        self.setattr(self,key,value)

    def setattr(self,c,key,value):
        if isinstance(value,str):
            value=f"{value}"
        eval(f"c._replace({key}={value})")

log=Log()

setattr(log,"x",4)

print(log.x) <--- i view alway 1
```

In my project i must use setAttr for change value to Class or NamedTuple because flag can be changed. So i cant use list or others.
What is best choice? I had thought to Dict or another Class but NamedTuple are very nice for me.

thanks
regards

Comment: It’s hard to understand what this is supposed to do. You have two definitions of `Log` and `LogNT` is only defined in some cases.

Comment: Just use a regular class. Immutability is a *feature* of tuples, if you *don't want the feature of tuples, then don't derive your type from tuple*

Comment: Or a dataclass. I don't know if they can be selectively frozen, or if it's a write-time all-or-nothing choice…